# How to sort results from SQL on a table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I want sort results from a MSSQL table but with sessions.. I have a code that works like '?sort=id' but I want make per sessions, anyone can help me?

```
                <?php   
                $ordenarpor = isset($_GET['ordena']) ? $_GET['ordena'] : 'id';
                $ordenar = '';
                if ($ordenarpor== 'id')
                {
                    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY id";
                }
                elseif ($ordenarpor== 'nome')
                {
                    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY nome";
                }
                elseif ($ordenarpor== 'idade')
                {
                    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY idade";
                }
                elseif($ordenarpor== 'peso')
                {
                    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY peso";
                }   
            $nomeServidor = "fsadaxa-DEMO"; 
            $opcao = array(  "UID" => "sa",  "PWD" => "sadasx",  "Database" => "demo");
            $conexao = sqlsrv_connect($nomeServidor, $opcao);
                if( $conexao ) {
                $sql="SELECT * FROM cliente" . $ordenar;
                $aResult=sqlsrv_query($conexao, $sql);
                while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($aResult))
                { 
                $id = $rows['id'];
                $nome = $rows['nome'];
                $idade = $rows['idade'];
                $peso = $rows['peso'];

                    ?>
```

Currently this is my code, but I want make it per sessions

Comment: keep track of the sort in the `$_SESSION` variable. Then check if `$_GET` isset, if it is, overwrite the `$_SESSION` variable with the new sort value

Comment: This question is much to vague. Sharing some code and pointing out the problem you're having with it will increase the chance we'll be able to help you.

Comment: I have added some code, if you can help me..

Comment: What do you mean by sessions? How can you sort by session?

Comment: It get info from ?odena=peso, per example but I dont want it all times. I want save all data at cache and sort it

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to set the `$_SESSION` variable when a new `$_GET` variable is set.
If no `$_GET` variable is set, use the `$_SESSION` variable instead.
If both are unset, use the default one : `'id'`.

```
$ordernarpor = 'id';
if(isset($_GET['orderna']))
{
    $ordernarpor = $_GET['orderna'];
    $_SESSION['orderna'] = $ordernarpor;
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['orderna']))
{
    $ordernarpor = $_SESSION['orderna'];
}
$ordenar = '';
if ($ordenarpor== 'id')
{
    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY id";
}
elseif ($ordenarpor== 'nome')
{
    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY nome";
}
elseif ($ordenarpor== 'idade')
{
    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY idade";
}
elseif($ordenarpor== 'peso')
{
    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY peso";
}   
$nomeServidor = "fsadaxa-DEMO"; 
$opcao = array(  "UID" => "sa",  "PWD" => "sadasx",  "Database" => "demo");
$conexao = sqlsrv_connect($nomeServidor, $opcao);
if( $conexao ) {
$sql="SELECT * FROM cliente" . $ordenar;
$aResult=sqlsrv_query($conexao, $sql);
while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($aResult))
{ 
    $id = $rows['id'];
    $nome = $rows['nome'];
    $idade = $rows['idade'];
    $peso = $rows['peso'];
```